# Implementing Case in TSQL

Tags: sql, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2, case

Good day everyone, I have this query:

```
SELECT B.fld_ActionName,
    ISNULL(A.COUNT, 0) count,
    ISNULL(A.GRAMS, 0) grams,
    ISNULL(A.PRINCIPAL, 0) principal
FROM #PULLEDOUT A
RIGHT JOIN Reference.tbl_RefAction B
    ON A.OSD = B.fld_ActionID
WHERE B.fld_ActionID IN (100, 200, 360, 454, 457)
```

I want the words on `B.fld_ActionName` to be transformed from and to as follows

```
New         (still the same no change)
Checked     (still the same no change)
For Recall -->recall
EL -->indexed EL
Watch -->Scrap watch
```

Is it possible? If yes then how? I really do not know if case is applicable to this, I'm new to TSQL and i do not know how to implement it.

Thank you

Comment: Have you even googled it? Check this: [CASE in TSQL](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/39103/A-Simple-Use-of-SQL-CASE-Expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT
  CASE b.fld_ActionName
   WHEN 'For Recall' THEN 'recall'
   WHEN 'EL' THEN 'indexed EL'
   WHEN 'Watch' THEN 'Scrap watch'
   ELSE b.fld_ActionName 
  END AS 'Action',
  ISNULL(A.COUNT,0) AS 'count',
  ISNULL(A.GRAMS,0) AS 'grams',
  ISNULL(A.PRINCIPAL,0) AS 'principal' 
FROM #PULLEDOUT A
RIGHT JOIN Reference.tbl_RefAction B
ON A.OSD =B.fld_ActionID
WHERE B.fld_ActionID in (100,200,360,454,457)
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
    CASE
        WHEN B.fld_ActionName IN ('New','Checked') THEN B.fld_ActionName
        WHEN B.fld_ActionName 'For Recall' THEN 'recall'
        WHEN B.fld_ActionName 'EL' THEN 'indexed EL'
        WHEN B.fld_ActionName 'Watch' THEN 'Scrap watch'
    END,
    ISNULL(A.COUNT,0) count,
    ISNULL(A.GRAMS,0) grams,
    ISNULL(A.PRINCIPAL,0) principal
FROM #PULLEDOUT A
     RIGHT JOIN Reference.tbl_RefAction B
         ON A.OSD =B.fld_ActionID
WHERE B.fld_ActionID in (100,200,360,454,457)
```

Comment: how would i implement it in the select statement?

Comment: @AsshO.Le Copy paste the statement?

Comment: @AsshO.Le I have edited the answer to the full SQL statement. Check it out.